# Is it normal to have a base type for Entities and Value Objects?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, inheritance

Please see the code below, which I am currently using in a production application. :

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }
 
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var compareTo = obj as Entity;
 
        if (ReferenceEquals(compareTo, null))
            return false;
 
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, compareTo))
            return true;
 
        if (GetRealType() != compareTo.GetRealType())
            return false;
 
        if (!IsTransient() && !compareTo.IsTransient() && Id == compareTo.Id)
            return true;
 
        return false;
    }
 
    public static bool operator ==(Entity a, Entity b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) && ReferenceEquals(b, null))
            return true;
 
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) || ReferenceEquals(b, null))
            return false;
 
        return a.Equals(b);
    }
 
    public static bool operator !=(Entity a, Entity b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
 
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (GetRealType().ToString() + Id).GetHashCode();
    }
 
    public virtual bool IsTransient()
    {
        return Id == 0;
    }
 
    public virtual Type GetRealType()
    {
        return NHibernateUtil.GetClass(this);
    }
}
```

Every Entity class inherits from it.

It is a slight variation of the code here: https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction/blob/master/DddInPractice.Logic/Common/Entity.cs

I am trying to decide whether to remove this base entity type from my application because of the feedback I have received when talking about it.

Is it normal to have a base Entity type (and base ValueObject) that has a base implementation for comparisons e.g. Object.Equals, IEquality.Equals etc?

It seems logical to me.  Say I have the following entities:

```
Customer
Supplier
Product
Production
etc
```

Why is it a bad idea for them all to be compared by ID by default?

I have a separate domain model and data model if that has any bearing.

Comment: How is it used?

Comment: @Mast, as it stands; the only reason I use it is to add Products to a HashSet.

Comment: I do not fully agree with original article about this approach. Forcing a base class in languages with single inheritance is too much. You can introduce a default implementation you will use most of times but **there must be an interface above. Not to mention that you're making your domain  objects aware of ORM** and it's even worse. Probably the point is to implement an EqualityComparer instead.

Comment: @ Adriano Repetti, thanks.  I really like the idea of creating an IEqualityComparer.  How is the Domain Model aware of the ORM if there is a separate data model?

Comment: In GetRealType() directly but also the other functions rely on ORM implementation details (IsTransient)

Comment: What's that feedback you've received that makes you doubt?

Comment: @Alejandro, as  Adriano Repetti says: "forcing a base class in languages with single inheritance is too much.". Also see this video by Eric Evans: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRCOKKUSp9s.  Do you use a base class?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's more about best practices than asking for a code review.

Answer (score 1):

#### Review

The following methods are candidates for properties. A property is expected to return fast, without too much calculations and internal flow. I'm assuming `NHibernateUtil.GetClass` provides a fast lookup.

> ```
> public virtual bool IsTransient()
> {
>     return Id == 0;
> }
>
> public virtual Type GetRealType()
> {
>     return NHibernateUtil.GetClass(this);
> }
> ```

```
public virtual bool IsTransient => Id == 0;
public virtual Type RealType => NHibernateUtil.GetClass(this);
```

---

#### When to use a base class

- Since C# allows for single class inheritance, pick a base class that adds sufficient state / operations to the class. Providing base classes like `EqualityBase`, `ComparableBase`, `DisposableBase`, `HashCodeBase` are bad choices, since they don't provide meaningful context except for a very specific mitigation of boiler-plate code. Which class should `Entity` implement of the above? You would like to implement all of them, but you can't!
- Is `Entity` provided by the OP a good choice for a base class? If the `IsTransient()` and `GetRealType()` methods weren't provided, I would argue against using a base class. You would end up with a class like above (`EqualityBase`, `HashCodeBase` mix). Both added methods allow for sufficient context to justify a base class.
- Use the power of **interface inheritance**, because you can implement as many interfaces as you want, and **composition**, because you can contain and delegate operations to as many contained objects you desire.

---

#### Dilemma

Using a base class allows for DRY code. The repetitive boiler-plate code sits in the base class, while the entities are very clean POCO's. However, you force the entities to derive from this base class, limiting the inheritance options for such classes drastically.

#### Solution

To allow for flexibility in inheritance options for your entities, and mitigating most boiler-plate code, you could provide an interface, a base class and let your entities implement both. The special entities that require to inherit from a different base class, should do so, and implement the interface.

```
public interface IEntity
{
    long Id { get; }
    bool IsTransient { get; }
    Type RealType { get; }
} 

public abstract class EntityBase : IEntity
{
    public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual bool IsTransient => Id == 0;
    public virtual Type RealType => NHibernateUtil.GetClass(this);

    // .. other code (equals, operator overloads, ..)
}
```

Most entities would implement both the base class and interface:

```
public class Employee : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string BadgeId { get; set; }
}
```

Allowing for special cases:

```
public class DocumentElement : TreeNode<DocumentElement>, IEntity
{
    // .. DocumentElement  members
    // .. IEntity members
}
```

Other layers using the entities don't care about the base class, only the interface.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
{
    T Get(int id);
    void Save(T entity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**WTF**

I'm imagining someone must have read about potential quirks coming from the Delta Quadrant of the C# universe and decided a top to bottom rewrite of equality behavior is needed, just to be safe. Yeah, those guys on the C# design and compiler team got nuttin' on me!

Re-implementing inherited behavior in an override is what is going on here. This is antithetical, contrary, to the fundamental point of OO inheritance.

Overriding `==` does give nice, concise expression but essentially everything else I see is WTF.

All that is required is a straight-forward `Equals` implementation so your custom class, collections, and comparisons in general, work as intended. The only gotcha I've ever covered (consciously on purpose) was when I had an `IEqualityComparer` and made sure to override `Equals` to also call it.

**The question makes no sense**

All c# objects have a base and inherit `Equals`, and always, ultimately, from `Object`. Bottom line, the `Equals` implementation must differentiate objects such that your collections, hash sets, etc. work as expected.

**The implementation makes no sense**

The default, inherited, `Object.Equals` implementation is `ReferenceEquals`.

A key point of inheritance is that base behavior does not need to be, should not be, duplicated in an override.

`ReferenceEquals(.., null)` - I'm sure there's some obscure point to this but in all the thousands of `Equals` overrides I've seen and written, this was not there.  Just check for `if (other == null) return false;`.  And the fact that `null` is not an object per-se makes `ReferenceEquals` look odd and quirky. NOTE: I've seen buggy `IComparer` / `CompareTo` where `null` caused an infinite loop but the problem there was coder incompetence and poor testing, not lack of `ReferenceEquals` in that class' `Equals` override implementation.

Comment: _The question makes no sense_ - yup, that's why I voted to close it (over a year ago) but unfortunatelly it's still open and confuses people. _WTF_ matches perfectly what this code ist ;-)

Comment: My main issue is this is in the wrong forum besides being "Huh??". But then I wonder if "what not to do" class of questions might be helpful - I thought "OMG! I gotta warn people, *do not do this!!!* -  but these may too susceptible to opinionation.